# MySQL Subquery / Query Issue

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a mental block with this query, I'm trying to return the max date and the maximum time and do an order by of the identity. It would be greatly appreciate if someone can add a pair of eyes to this type of query So :

Data Set

```
Identity, Date, Time, Website
10, 5/10/15, 1,  google.com 
10,  5/10/15, 3, google.com
10, 5/10/15, 10, google.com 
25, 5/11/15, 1, yahoo.com
25, 5/11/15, 15, yahoo.com
```

Expected Result

```
10, 5/10/15, 10, google.com  
25, 5/11/15, 15, yahoo.com
```

Current Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT *, MAX(datetime) as maxdate, MAX(time), identity
FROM identity_track 
GROUP BY identity 
ORDER BY maxdate DESC
```

Comment: I don't know why expected is "10, 5/10/15, 3, google.com" instead of "10, 5/10/15, 10, google.com"?

Comment: Right. Why are you expecting 3 not 10 for the time ?.

Comment: You're correct, 3 should be 10. updating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
select identity, max(date), max(time), website
  from identity_track
  group by website;
```

Demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5cadf/1

You can order by any of the fields you want.

Also, the expected output you posted doesn't line up with what it seems like you're attempting to do.

**edit**

Updated query based on additional information.

```
select t.identity, t.date, max(t.time), t.website
  from t
    inner join
     (select identity, website, max(date) d
       from t
       group by identity, website) q
    on t.identity = q.identity
      and t.website = q.website
      and q.d = t.date
   group by t.identity, t.website, t.date
```

This one should give you the users identity, the pages he visited, the last time he visited that page, and the most amount of time he spent in any visit on that last visit.

Comment: This looks good so far, the one issue I'm running into actually is if a identity has two domains.. it throws the entire data for a loop. In example if identity 10 had went to yahoo.com and google.com the maxtime is no longer valid.

Comment: what the hell does your identity field mean if it can go to two websites? also, why is your time value separate to your date? the way it is means there's an issue with my query. If it was just a single datetime field, it would be as simple as the answer currently stands

Comment: The identity would be the unique identifier of the user. As one user could have viewed many websites.  So the result would need to show a result for yahoo.com and google.com for the identity of 10.

Comment: I see. thanks. it wasn't clear from your sample data

Comment: The time field would represent the time spent on that specific website and the datetime would be currently recording when they first land on it.

Comment: that makes more sense - and what are you trying to find? the most recent day they visited the page, and the most time they spent on it in that day? or the most recent day they visisted, and the most they spent on it, ever?

Comment: Exactly, you're spot on. I'm going to try your query.  Greatly appreciated.

Comment: There was a typo that should be fixed now

Comment: Yeap, I saw that too. Perfect...this looks like the path I'm going down. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Don't assume that all records for an identity are on the same day e.g. if the entity has times of 1/1/15 5pm and 1/2/15 2pm you'd get 1/2/15 5pm which is wrong.

I'd always merge the time and date but if you can't try this:

```
select t.identity, t.website, MAX(t.time)
FROM t
     INNER JOIN
           (
            select identity, max(date) as max_date
              from t
              group by identity;
            ) x
            ON t.identity = x.identity
            AND t.date = x.max_date
group by t.identity, t.website
```

Firstly we get the maximum date for each site. Then for that day, get the maximum time.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I'll take a look into your solution also.